# Which of the following can be inferred from the statements given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

> P and Q are positive Integers.P leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $20$ and Q leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $20$.

Consider the folllowing statements

$1$) ($2^P$-$2$P)   is divisible by $10$

$2$) ($8^Q$-$8$Q)   is divisible by $10$

Which of the following can be concluded?

a)Only $1$ is true

b)Only $2$ is true

c)Both $1$ and $2$ are true

d)Neither 1) nor 2) is true

**MyApproach**

($2^P$-$2$ . P)  equation  No 1

($8^Q$-$8$ . Q)   equation No 2

I calculated

P=$20$k+$1$=>$2$P=>$40$k+$2$

Q=$20$k+$2$=8Q=$160$k+$16$

Substituting these values in eqn ..1 and eq..2 I am not getting any Ans.

> Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: I can't follow your notation. What does $(2^P - 2 \, . \, P)$ mean?

Comment: @BrandonCarter  I edited the code